# Rspec: How to get the current context from inside a custom matcher?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Is there a way to get the current context from inside of a custom matcher?

```rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_the_same do |expected|
  match do |actual|
     ###### Is there a way to get the context *here* #####
     ###### Basically some function that returns 'some context' ###
     actual == expected
    end
  end
end

RSpec.describe do 
  context 'some context' do 
    it { expect(1).to be_the_same(1) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Why would you need a matcher that depends not on actual/expected values, but the context too? Could you show an imaginary usage example, please?

Comment: `it` will yield the the `Example` object to the block you could pas this to the matcher if you wanted I guess. Technically speaking the matcher has access to the execution context (the `ExampleGroup` not the example itself) but not "publicly". For example inside the match bock `self.instance_variable_get(:@matcher_execution_context).class.description #=> "some context"` this is not the same as the example e.g. `it {|x| puts(x.description)} #=> "example at ./file_spec.rb:[line_no]"`

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov, my matcher calls an external API and I want to record these calls with VCR. I want to get some information about the context in which the matcher is run so I could use it to identify the VCR tape to use.

Comment: @frmsaul this still seems like a bad idea. Based on your description this could easily be replaced with shared examples (as suggested below). You can maintain your own context using these and use `let` or `it` blocks to execute and record the API responses as needed. This [gist](https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/2377461) offers a nice rundown of options

Answer (score 0):

Custom matchers are not meant to have access to the test context as they are scoped to the params given through actual and expected. If you need to have access to the spec context you are better off using shared examples as they will suit your DRY needs.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#providing-context-to-a-shared-group-using-a-block